# Cannot Write String to FileWriter/BufferedWriter

Tags: java, google-authenticator

I am trying to make an application that will create Google Authenticator secret keys, as well as authenticate the OTP. I am writing all of my passwords to individual files titled with the name that goes along with them.

First and foremost, I am using this library.
https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-otp-java

This is my code:

```
public void createUserFile(String name) throws IOException
{
    File file = new File("users\\" + name + ".txt");
    file.createNewFile();
}

public void generateUserKey(String name)
{
    try 
    {
        File file = new File("users\\" + name + ".txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        String s = Base32.random();
        out.write(s);
        out.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If I change the value of `s` to something like "Hello" I am fine. However, it will not write that random string. That is what I need help with. I have tinkered and searched hours for answers, and I have found nothing.

Comment: What does `Base32.random()` return?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels [`Base32`](https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-otp-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/aerogear/security/otp/api/Base32.java)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Base32.random returns a string.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you need `createUserFile`, and it isn't clear you necessarily know where the "users/" folder (a relative path) is. I suggest you use [`System.getProperty(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) to get [`user.home`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) (the *User home directory*).

I would also suggest you use a [`try-with-resources` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). Something like

```
public void generateUserKey(String name) {
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), //
            String.format("%s.txt", name));
    try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(file)) {
        ps.print(Base32.random());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ElliotFrisch In the original code, it creates a directory in the root folder of the program. Is this doing the same thing, or is it taking from the user folder in windows?

Comment: @JamesDepp Your posted code doesn't create a directory.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I created a directory already, I just didn't post that part of the code because I thought it was a bit irrelevant. Even so, I tried the code, and it didn't work.Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Then change `System.getProperty("user.home")` to that directory.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Regardless, it doesn't print the text to the file.

Comment: @JamesDepp I believe it does, but that file isn't where you believe it is.